# html files on google chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome

So, I cannot open index.html files on google chrome. My file has defaulted on chrome. When I click on the files, it opens on google chrome. But, nothing loads on that page. I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Can you show me the content of the html file?

Comment: Well, browsers normally do this just fine, so the problem is likely with your file. Share the contents of your html file.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/257799/google-chrome-no-longer-opens-local-html-files-when-i-double-click-them

Answer (score 0):

If you have VScode, I highly recommend download Live Server plugin. That will help you to work with your HTML files.